# Fastest way to subtract pointer array by a constant

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a very large array of type (short*). How do I subtract all values by a constant in the fastest manner?

Comment: You want to subtract from the pointer? The value the pointer points to? Can you show an example with some of your data and the expected result?

Comment: Umm, what's wrong with for-loop? If you are really in need of speed, then maybe threads will help? Divide up your array and create some threads to carry out the subtraction on the chunks

Comment: @smac89 Threads can help only if you have multiple cores, otherwise the overhead of maintaining the threads will just slow things down.

Comment: I want to subtract from the value the pointer points to. Basically all of my values will be offset by a constant say 8504 and need to be able to adjust in the fastest manner without wasting cpu cycles.

Comment: Essentially I have have a very large array pointer and each of the values the pointer points to need to be subtracted from 8504 as fast as possible.

Comment: Do you really need to adjust the actual values, or can you instead apply the offset where the value is used?

Answer (score 0):

Using a for loop is indeed the most efficient way to do this

```
short *arr = new short[1000000];
const short c = 8504;

//populate the array
     Populate(arr); //just some method to populate the array

    for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++){
      arr[i] = c - arr[i] ;//subtract from the constant
    //or even
    //*arr = c - *arr++ ; 
    }
```

This code doesn't check for type overflows though.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to recalculate the actual values, you can calculate it ad hoc on usage:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct OffsetShort {
    short value;
    static short offset;
    operator short() const { return value - offset; }
};
short OffsetShort::offset = 0;
int main() {
    OffsetShort *vals[] = {new OffsetShort{1},new OffsetShort{2},new OffsetShort{3}};
    for (auto f : vals) {
        cout << *f;
    }
    OffsetShort::offset = 10;
    for (auto f : vals) {
        cout << *f;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this prints

```
123
-9-8-7
```